# How to edit image online on own site

Tags: asp.net, image, web

Hot to add functionality to the site that allows users upload, edit online and save images? Edit - resize, rotate, some color effects. Maybe there are some frameworks? The target platform is asp.net mvc 5.

Comment: There's a great API you can integrate in your app. ImageResizer, http://imageresizing.net/

Comment: If you could accept my answer it would be much appreciated. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a great API you can integrate in your app.
[ImageRsizing](http://imageresizing.net)